# Not seeing people use interfaces and @Transactional in their Spring Applications

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have been seeing this trend recently with some Spring Framework developers. When they create their Service classes they are not creating interfaces for them to implement and they are not using @Transactional in their service classes when they are definitely in need of transactions.

Is there a good reason for this?

And one more question, Spring Boot has Session In View set to be true. Why? I always thought that to be a really bad design, allowing for developers to be lazy and allow for N+1 queries to happen all the time and slowing down performance. If you know you are going to need it for the UI, why not query for it in the Service-Repository classes in the least amount of queries instead?

Comment: If all modifications are done in one query per call, then transactions would have no effect. However, if that is not the case, they are running the risk of an error ruining the integrity of the data.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by one query per call. Almost all Service methods would be doing many queries to the database to fulfill the use case and should be within a transactional boundary. Unless you mean Controller to just do an new Customer and it calls Service that only does the save() call and therefore just one query down to the database. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 2):

It's true that building Services with interfaces and class implementations has been under questioning lately. There a classic post about this: https://octoperf.com/blog/2016/10/27/impl-classes-are-evil/ .

About Transactions, for read operations the `readOnly=true` parameter should be included in the `@Transactional` annotation to make sure it is done properly. As for the write operations, of course the transaction management should be done with care and the `@Transactional` annotation is there to make sure it is done so. Not using it is certainly a code smell, since a transaction will happen nonetheless, but you just won't have control over it.

Session In View set to true is a code smell too, and it should be used in learning environments or short-term experiments only. Batching, among other possibilities, can and should be used to avoid the N+1 problem.

Comment: Thanks Julio. Yeah, I see no Transactional annotation on their code, and that means that the transactions are only being handled on the database end. I know that Spring set session in view because of Controllers and Jackson where Jackson traverses down @ManyToOnes which are lazy loaded. Thanks for the reply